# Hyper-V machine on Server 2012 losing connectivity randomly

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012

I have start using Hyper-V on my Microsoft Windows 2012 Server, hosting a 2012 server.

But randomly my virtual machine loosing connections, i see it now when i trying to copy data to it from a old server to this new one.

Both MySQL and FTP connections loosings randomly.

I have searched for this problem and finded that in server 2008 there was some problem and Microsoft got a hotfix for it but that for 2008 server so not for 2012.

I have tried all except the hotfix on this Question: [Why are my HyperV VM's randomly losing connectivity?](https://serverfault.com/questions/278860/why-are-my-hyperv-vms-randomly-losing-connectivity)

Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: What brand NICs? Have you updated firmware and drivers?

Comment: Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller, going to try to get latest drivers.

Comment: Get a server-grade NIC?  Something nice from Intel perhaps?

Comment: I using a hosted server from hetzner.dk so can not select so match.

Comment: Have you solved your issue? I have the same problem with the same hardware...